# Can't get result when running the query from Spring Data Jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

When running the following query in pgAdmin, everything is good but when I run the query from java code i get an error.

I tried to cast the variables but no result, I get an error of cast syntax

The query interface:

```
public interface SeanceRepository extends JpaRepository<Seance, Integer>{

    @Query(value = "select * from seance, patient where extract(month from date) = ?1 "
            + "and extract(year from date) = ?2 and patient.id = seance.patient_id", 
              nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object> getSeanceByMonthYear(String month, String year);
}
```

The error :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: l'opérateur n'existe pas : double precision = character varying
  Indice : Aucun opérateur ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
Vous devez ajouter des conversions explicites de type.
  Position : 62
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
```

Patient.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String cin;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Boolean active;

    //getters and setters
}
```

seance.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Seance")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Seance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private Date date;

    @OneToOne
    private Patient patient;

    @OneToOne
    private TypeConsultation typeConsultation;

    private String motif;

    //getters and setters
```

Comment: can you please translate the error message to english?

Comment: @Jens ```error operator does not exist double precision = character varying```

Comment: Looks like `extract(month from date)` does not return a character. Try to explicite cast it

Answer (score 2):

It is because the function extract a double and you compare it to a string

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/extract-function.php

> The extract function() is used to retrieves subfields such as year or
>   hour from date/time values. The source must be a value expression of
>   type timestamp, time, or interval. The field is an identifier or
>   string that selects what field to be extracted from the source value.
>
> Syntax:
>
> extract(field from timestamp) or extract(field from interval)
>
> Return Type: double precision.
>
> PostgreSQL Version: 9.3

extract returns a value in double presision and you try to compare it to a varchar. It can not be done by postgresSQL automatically, you have to do it explicitly:

```
@Query(value = "select * from seance, patient where extract(month from date)::varchar(255) = ?1 "
        + "and extract(year from date)::varchar(255) = ?2 and patient.id = seance.patient_id", 
          nativeQuery = true)
```